# How to Convert RGB images dataset to single channel grayscale?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rgb, shapes

I'm facing a problem that when i feed my cnn with grayscale images dataset, it reads it as 3-Channels images not as single channel.

so how to convert the 3 channels images to **single channel** grayscale images ?

Comment: ... don't know how you managed to not include even one appropriate tag...! (edited now)

Comment: @desertnaut Absolute minimum effort to solve the problem, especially given that there's a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html) on this in the OpenCV docs (and probably a billion duplicates on SO).

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you directly read images as grayscale with:

```
im_gray = cv2.imread('gray_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

or you can convert an rgb image to grayscale with:

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```